# Retrieving data from databse using the dropdown selected list in php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have texbox and dropdown list which is populated from mysql database. I want to retrieve data from database and wants to display in textbox using dropdown selected list, without refreshing the page. Here is my code and Thanks in Advance.

```
<select name="select1" class="form-control" id="dropdownlist1">
      <option id="0">-- Select the Company --</option>
      <?php
          require("dbcon.php");

          $getallcompanies = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ifcandetails6");

          while($viewallcompanies = mysql_fetch_array($getallcompanies)){
              ?>
      <option id="<?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcuid']; ?>"><?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcname'] ?></option>
      <?php
          }
           ?>

  </select>
```

Input Textbox:

```
 <input type="text" id="field1" value="<?php echo $viewallcompanies['tccontact']?>" disabled/>
```

Comment: Dont iterate inside the `select`. First do you sql queries, then break them down to variables. Lastly use those variables where you need them. Separation is key.

Comment: where do you want that textbox? will it ony be one?

Comment: i want to Populate Mutiple Textbox with single dropdown list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate things out like this:

```
<?php

require("dbcon.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT tcuid, tcname, tccontact FROM ifcandetails6");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $contacts[] = $row['tccontact'];
    $companies[] = $row;   
}
?>

<select name="select1" class="form-control" id="dropdownlist1">
    <option id="0">-- Select the Company --</option>
    <?php foreach($companies as $company) { ?>
        <option id="<?= $company['tcuid']; ?>"><?= $company['tcname'] ?></option>
    <?php }  ?>
</select>
<?php foreach($contacts as $contact) { ?>
    <input type="text" id="field1" value="<?= $contact['tccontact']?>"/>
<?php }  ?>
```